# How to avoid my twitter account getting suspended?

Tags: php, api, twitter, product, affiliates

I am going to promote my product affiliate website through twitter, Where my activities are getting all the tweets based on some keywords(ex: Red shoe). Then ill reply to the tweet like "please check my link http://www.affliateexample.com/redshoe". Im having huge tweet data so planning to execute a cron file to reply all these tweets through my tweet application(php) . Is that a right way to do this work or this will get suspend my twitter account. Please advise on this...

Comment: The problem you're facing is dat a) suspension can be based on an account sending spam, and b) your account is made to send spam. In the end the only real solution would be to "not do this".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, what you're doing is considered spam by both the ToS ([1](https://twitter.com/tos), [2](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms)) and the users. Stop doing it.

For the record, I always report accounts that automatically mention me based on keywords. With me a thousand others. I think it's safe to assume that even if your account wouldn't get flagged automatically, enough users will click the report button for your account to get suspended.

*Full disclosure: I work for Twitter in The Netherlands, as an internationalization moderator*

Comment: Thanks Nanne and tom .. So is there any other alternative way to achieve this.. Because im not giving my direct affiliate link in twitter. im giving my own website link where all the affiliate products are listed .I just getting many visitors to website.. When the visitor clicks any of the product. Then they will redirect to affiliate links.

Comment: Twitter isn't an advertisement platform, but a network where people communicate. If you want to promote your products to people, that *could* be fine, but only if they follow you. Just post a tweet and your followers will get it.

Alternatively, you might want to consider [Twitter's advertisement program](https://business.twitter.com/en/advertise/start/).